# how to write in django restapi[POST] to add database values of field1 and field2 to field3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

while inserting data through post in django restapi how to write a function to add filed values? EX: column1:900  ,column2:1000,  column3=column2-column1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in serializer class

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('f1', 'f2', 'f3',)
        extra_kwargs = {'f3':{'read_only':True,},}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        f1 = validated_data['f1']
        f2 = validated_data['f2']

        f3 = f1 + f2
        obj = MyModel(f1=f1, f2=f2, f3=f3)
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Comment: it is useful for me